# sql server 2012 - check constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. Below is what I have to write. I would really appreciate some help.

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [constraintname] CHECK  
(([column]='A' OR [column]='B' OR [column]='C' OR [column]='D'))
```

But when we generate the script through SQL Server 2012 Management Studio, i am getting the below statements..

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [constraintname] CHECK  
(([column]='A' OR [column]='B' OR [column]='C' OR [column]='D'))
GO
ALTER TABLE [tablename] CHECK CONSTRAINT [constraintname]
```

Why the generated script first constructed with nocheck and then apply check on the table? What will happen if i create the check constraint without nocheck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated script uses NOCHECK, so the constraint will always be created, even if the values in the table don't comply. This is better for an automatically generated script, because it ensures the database schema will be created or amended correctly.

I thought at first, that the second statement in the generated script is to ensure that the Query Optimizer will consider the constraint. (See reference below.) However, on further investigation, it seems that the second statement doesn't have any effect -- see my second answer.

When you are doing it manually, using WITH CHECK, you can see straight away that the statement has failed and take corrective action. Then run the statement again.

If you use the WITH NOCHECK option, you might not notice that the data is invalid. Personally, I always use WITH CHECK when doing ALTER TABLE to add constraints. Also Books Online says that using WITH NOCHECK is not recommended, except in rare cases -- see references below.

To demonstrate the difference, let's first create a table and insert some values.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T
(
    id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [column] nchar(1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.T ([column])
    VALUES (N'A'), (N'B'), (N'C'), (N'E');
```

Try to alter the table and add a constraint, specifying WITH CHECK. This fails because some of the data in the table does not comply with the constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T
    WITH CHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Column CHECK ([column] IN (N'A', N'B', N'C', N'D'));
```

[image]

Let's see if the constraint has been created, by using the sys.check_constraints system catalog view. This shows the constraint has not been created.

```
SELECT *
    FROM sys.check_constraints
    WHERE [parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T');
```

[image]

Try again, this time specifying WITH NOCHECK. This time it completes successfully. However, there is no warning that the data in the table is invalid, which might be undesirable.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T
    WITH NOCHECK
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Column CHECK ([column] IN (N'A', N'B', N'C', N'D'));
```

[image]

And we can verify that the check constraint has been created.

[image]

See Books Online > ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190273.aspx > WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK

> If you do not want to verify new CHECK or FOREIGN KEY constraints against existing data, use WITH NOCHECK. We do not recommend doing this, except in rare cases. The new constraint will be evaluated in all later data updates. Any constraint violations that are suppressed by WITH NOCHECK when the constraint is added may cause future updates to fail if they update rows with data that does not comply with the constraint.

The reason for the second automatically generated statement is revealed here:

> The query optimizer does not consider constraints that are defined WITH NOCHECK. Such constraints are ignored until they are re-enabled by using ALTER TABLE table WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL.

Answer (score 1):

Digging a bit deeper after my previous answer...

If we run the following statement after creating the CHECK constraint with the WITH NOCHECK option, we can see that the constraint is enabled (is_disabled = 0), but it is not trusted.

```
SELECT name, is_disabled, is_not_trusted
    FROM sys.check_constraints
    WHERE [parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T');
```

[image]

Running the second statement generated by SSMS, makes no difference. The check constraint is still not trusted and it was already enabled.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T
    CHECK CONSTRAINT CK_Column;
```

We have to fix the data. (Or alter the constraint.)

```
UPDATE dbo.T
    SET [column] = N'D'
    WHERE [column] = N'E';
```

Then run this statement. Note that this time we are specifying WITH CHECK, so the data gets verified.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T
    WITH CHECK
    CHECK CONSTRAINT CK_Column;
```

Then finally we can see that the constraint becomes trusted (is_not_trusted = 0), which means it can be used by the Query Optimizer.

```
SELECT name, is_disabled, is_not_trusted
    FROM sys.check_constraints
    WHERE [parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T');
```

[image]

So, in summary, the second statement generated by SSMS serves no useful purpose as far as I can see, because the constraint is already enabled.

See Books Online > sys.check_constraints (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187388.aspx

Also see Books Online > ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190273.aspx > { CHECK | NOCHECK } CONSTRAINT

> Specifies that constraint_name is enabled or disabled. This option can only be used with FOREIGN KEY and CHECK constraints. When NOCHECK is specified, the constraint is disabled and future inserts or updates to the column are not validated against the constraint conditions. DEFAULT, PRIMARY KEY, and UNIQUE constraints cannot be disabled.

SQLServerCentral.com > A Check and Foreign Key Constraint Improves Query Performance: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/71264/